# PostGIS: Syncronizing timecodes by GPS point

Tags: postgresql, distance, latitude-longitude, postgis, geo

I have several video tracks of the same route, shot on different occasions throughout the year. All the video tracks are GPS-tagged with a 1Hz GPS, so I have second-by-second GPS points of all the shots.

What I'd like to accomplish is to put all these video tracks into e.g. After Effects, and remap the time by GPS location. I can't sync the tracks by time, seeing as the route includes stoplights and other obstacles.

I've started out creating two tables: One called summer, which is the main video track, and one called shot, which encompasses all the others.

The summer table looks like this:

```
      Column   |          Type          |                             Modifiers                              | Storage | Description 
-----------+------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------
 id        | integer                | not null default nextval('summer_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   | 
 timecode  | time without time zone | not null                                                           | plain   | 
 spring_id | integer                |                                                                    | plain   | 
 autumn_id | integer                |                                                                    | plain   | 
 winter_id | integer                |                                                                    | plain   | 
 point     | geometry(Point,4326)   | not null                                                           | main    | 

Indexes:
    "summer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "summer_autumn_id" btree (autumn_id)
    "summer_point_id" gist (point)
    "summer_spring_id" btree (spring_id)
    "summer_winter_id" btree (winter_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "summer_autumn_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (autumn_id) REFERENCES shot(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "summer_spring_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (spring_id) REFERENCES shot(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "summer_winter_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (winter_id) REFERENCES shot(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Has OIDs: no
```

While the shot table looks like this:

```
  Column  |          Type          |                             Modifiers                             | Storage  | Description 
----------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-------------
 id       | integer                | not null default nextval('shot_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    | 
 season   | character varying(255) | not null                                                          | extended | 
 timecode | time without time zone | not null                                                          | plain    | 
 point    | geometry(Point,4326)   | not null                                                          | main     | 

Indexes:
    "shot_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "shot_point_id" gist (point)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "summer" CONSTRAINT "summer_autumn_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (autumn_id) REFERENCES shot(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "summer" CONSTRAINT "summer_spring_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (spring_id) REFERENCES shot(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "summer" CONSTRAINT "summer_winter_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (winter_id) REFERENCES shot(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Has OIDs: no
```

So, basically what I want to do, is to run through all the rows in the summer table, find the point closest to each row for each of the different takes, and update the summer table with this information.

I've put together a query that I personally don't see why doesn't work, but the output is weird, and doesn't work at all with time remapping in After Effects:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (summer.id)
   summer.id AS summer_id, shot.id AS autumn_id,
   ST_Distance_Sphere(summer.point, shot.point) AS distance
FROM shot.summer summer
   LEFT JOIN shot.shot.track
     ON ST_DFullyWithin (summer.point, shot.point, 0.001)
     AND shot.season='autumn'
ORDER BY summer.id ASC;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess from my side (maybe you could elaborate a bit on "The output is weird"?)

You are using geographical coordinates, then a radius of 0.001 is a quite large distance (approx 100 m north-south, less east-west, depending on how far north you are) Then you will probably get a lot of matching hits in the two tables. As far as I understand, you want one "summer point" for each "autumn point" - you need to pick out just the closest point. Also, I would reproject the data into a projection that has the same x and y resolution, (e.g. utm unless you are covering too large east-west distances) Were I am, at about 60deg north, using a geographical projection, a ~ 110 meters north-south distance makes a numerical difference of 0.001 degrees, whereas a ~55 meters east-west distance gives the same numerical difference. I.e. for the calculations 55 meters error eastwards is the same as a 110 meters errors northwards... (if you are closer to the equator, the difference will be less, farther off and it will be worse)

Hope this pointed you in the right direction.